# NSLog Can see what Expression Watcher Cannot in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I wonder why?

By the way anyone can see the screen shot?[image: Screen Shot]
[image: It looks like simple expression works. When the number of dots become 2 it no longer does.]

Comment: And I wonder what your problem is

Comment: Please don't post links to your problem. Put a description of the problem in the body of your question. If you can't be bothered to type out your question, then I can't be bothered to help you.

Comment: Sorry. The link points to a picture. The screenshot I put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to expand self and then on currentproperty

Comment: It's core data object, not regular ones. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Print Description is greyed out :)

Comment: I think because Building is a subclass of NSManagedObject... It could be that XCode couldn't read core data objects from the debugger. You can try to fill a ticket to Apple Bug Report if you think this is a bug